# How to Build dependent picklists in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, dependent-picklist, lightning-combobox

I need to control a product Combobox by Pricebook Combobox in Lightning Web Component

I've created an LWC that contains two comboboxes: Pricebook list and Product list. I was able to get the list of Pricebooks using an apex method and displayed it as Combobox and when I choose a Pricebook, I can get its id in a change handler method in JS, but I do not know how to call a second apex method which is supposed to return the list of products filtered by the selected pricebook, and update the Products Combobox ?

HTML :

```html
<template>
      <lightning-card title="List of products">
             <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                     <lightning-combobox class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-6" name="Pricebooks"
                                            label="Pricebooks"
                                            placeholder="-Select Pricebook-"
                                            value={value}
                                            options={pricebookOptions}
                                            onchange={pricebookChange} >
                      </lightning-combobox>
                      <lightning-combobox class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-6" name="Products"
                                            label="Products"
                                            placeholder="-Select Product-"
                                            options={productOptions}
                                            onchange={...} >
                      </lightning-combobox>
              </div>
      </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS :

```js
export default class PriceBookPickList extends LightningElement {

    @track items = []; //this holds the array for records with value & label
    @track error;
    @track value;

    @wire(getPricebookObjects)
    pricebookList({error, data}){
      if(data){
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
         this.items = [...this.items,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name}];                                   
        }                
        this.error = undefined;
      }else if(error){
          this.error=error;
      }
    }
    get pricebookOptions(){
        return this.items;
    }
    pricebookChange(event) {
            console.log("ID IS " + event.detail.value);
    }
}
```

Apex :

```java
public with sharing class PricebookController {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Pricebook2> getAllPricebooks() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricebook2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another apex method `getProducts` which accepts `pricebookId` as parameter and returns list of products. Now in LWC js, implement wire service on that apex method which depends on dynamic property `$pricebookId`. As this is dynamic property, this wired service is invoked again when the property changes and not undefined.

```
pricebookChange(event) {
    console.log('ID IS ' + event.detail.value);
    this.pricebookId = event.detail.value;
}
@wire(getProducts, { pricebookId: '$pricebookId' })
prodsList({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        // handle products
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Notice that because we are setting new value to `pricebookChange` in `pricebookChange` method, the dependent wired service `prodsList` will get invoked and returns the results.

Comment: Thank you @salesforce-sas, your solution was perfect.